# If $A$ is 5 by 3 and $B$ is 3 by 5 (with dependent columns), is $AB = I$ impossible?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, matrix-rank

Let me first introduce the problem. This is part of the quiz problem from MIT's 18.06 course (Spring 2012 semester, quiz 1, problem 3). My question is related to (b) but (a) is mentioned in the solution to (b). So I included (a) as well.

#### (a) Suppose three matrices satisfy $AB = C$. If the columns of $B$ are dependent, show that the columns of $C$ are dependent.

> *Solution* 
> The columns of $B$ being dependent means by definition that there is a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Bx = 0$. But then we also
>   have $$Cx = (AB)x = A(Bx) = A(0) = 0.$$ which means that the columns
>   of $C$ are dependent.

#### (b) If $A$ is 5 by 3 and $B$ is 3 by 5, show using part (a) or otherwise that $AB = I$ is impossible.

> *Solution*
>   The columns of *B* are dependent, since these are five vectors in
>   $\mathbb R^3$, and $5>3$. Thus, by part (a), the columns of $AB$ must
>   be dependent. However, columns of $I$ are independent, so $AB$ can
>   never equal $I$. [Note: Switching the order matters here. One can indeed
>   find a $3\times 5$ matrix $A$, and a $5\times 3$ matrix $B$ such that
>   $AB = I$ is the $3 \times 3 $ identity - hence any "proof" that is
>   insensitive to the order of $A$ and $B$ must be flawed.]

My question is related to the text inside the angled bracket ("Note: Switching..."). I don't understand how "One can indeed find a $3\times 5$ matrix $A$, and a $5\times 3$ matrix $B$ such that $AB = I$ is the $3 \times 3 $ identity."

The following is my reasoning.

In this reverse scenario, $A$ is $3 \times 5 $ and $B$ is $5 \times 3 $. So $C = AB$ is $3 \times 3$. Because $B$ has dependent columns, its rank $r_B < 3$. $AB = C$ means that each row of $C$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$ (coefficient being the corresponding row of $A$). Then the dimension of the row space of $C$ is at most that of $B$ (i.e., $r_B$). Because a dimension of a row space is equal to a rank, the rank of $C$, $r_C \leq r_B < 3$. Because $C$ has 3 columns, $r_C < 3$ implies that the columns of $C$ are dependent.

Is my reasoning incorrect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When we say that a matrix is of size $r\times c$ the matrix has $r$ rows and $c$ columns.  Always robbers and cops, rumrunners and coastguards, rows and columns.  Try to be in the habit of always saying the words in that order, never in the other order.  What size is $AB$ then?  $5\times 5$ or $3\times 3$?  What is the maximum rank?

Comment: Thanks. I was referring to row $\times$ column. There are two scenarios considered. For the first scenario $AB$ is $5 \times 5$ and second scenario (which is the one I am interested in), $AB$ is $3 \times 3$.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the full problem statement for the question you are asking.  The hypothesis that $B$ has linearly dependent columns applies *only* to part (a).  Once we move to question (b) all hypotheses are reset and we no longer know anything about the dependence of the columns of $B$.  Notice that in the book's solution the very first thing they do is *prove* that in that specific case of $B$ being a $3\times 5$ matrix that it must have dependent columns.  If having dependent columns was a hypothesis here, it would not need to have been proven.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand the problem statement correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reasoning

> Because $B$ has dependent columns, its rank $r_B < 3$.

is not generally true. In the original proof, since $B$ is a $3 \times 5$ matrix, it is legit to the columns of $B$ are dependent. However, in the later setting, $B$ is a $5 \times 3$ matrix, this is not necessarily true.

In fact, whether $B$ is full column rank determines whether there exists such a $3 \times 5$ matrix $A$ such that $AB = I_3$.

It may be somehow confusing when we have different definitions for the matrices $A$ and $B$ in the two statements. We can unify and conclude as follows:

> Suppose $B$ is a $3 \times 5$ matrix. Then
>
> 1. For any $5 \times 3$ matrix $A$, the $5 \times 5$ matrix $AB$ cannot be the identity matrix $I_5$.
> 2. There may or may not exist a $5 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that the $3 \times 3$ matrix $BA$ is the identity matrix $I_3$. The existence depends on whether $\text{rank}(B) = 3$.

Comment: What do you mean by "in general" incorrect? Either the first statement you highlighted is correct or it isn't. And it happens to be correct.

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix},$
$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$
Your first claim is, in general, correct.

Comment: I think the way I described my question is a bit confusing. $B$ always has dependent columns given by the problem statement. The matrix $B$ [Aweygan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/234668/aweygan) provided has independent columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reminders. The first statement is correct. I missed the point that $A$ and $B$ are arbitrarily chosen given their size, and thought $B$ is given matrix. Nevertheless I think the final conclusion is clear.

Comment: Could you explain why you said my statement "Because $B$ has dependent columns, its rank $r_B \leq 3$ is not generally correct? $B$ here has $5 \times 3$. Because the columns are dependent, the rank should be less than 3, no?

Comment: @hwchung Let me clarify it here: If $B$ does have dependent columns, then it is true that $\text{rank}(B) < 3$. But it is not guaranteed that a $5 \times 3$ matrix has dependent columns. On the other hand, it is always true that a $3 \times 5$ matrix $B$ has dependent columns. After all it depends on the setting of your problem. I think in the note of the solution it is not mentioned that the $5 \times 3$ matrix $B$ has dependent columns

Comment: @S.W.Cheung Ah, I misunderstood the part (b) of the problem. I thought that B always has dependent columns is a given condition. The solution for part (b), as you explained, is just saying $B$ has dependent columns because it has more columns than rows. I guess my reasoning ($r_C\leq r_B<3$) is consistent with your 2nd conclusion because my reasoning assumes that $B$ does not have full column rank (which was the source of my confusion).